# How do you switch between inputs in php?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Let's say depending on which button I click I want the user to get a dropdown list or an input field. Basically either choose an existing one or create a new one.

```
<select name="choose[rowId]"></select>
<input name="choose[rowId]"/>
```

I'm using javascript do display one of the options above. Is there a way to have this work, without the first `name` overwriting the second?

They need to have the same name because they represent the same thing. I can't just add the second one with javascript if needed because I calculate the `rowId` with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make a javascript similar to this example:

jsFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2u9b4txk/

```
<div id="my_option">
    <select name="choose[rowId]">
        <option value="option 1">Existing Opt 1</option>
        <option value="option 3">Existing Opt 2</option>
        <option value="option 2">Existing Opt 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="my_option_new">
  <div id="add-opt">CREATE NEW</div>
</div>
<!-- requires jQuery library or refactoring for vanilla JS -->
<script>
$('#add-opt').on('click', function(){
  $('#my_option_new').html('<input name="choose[rowId]"  placeholder="Add new option" />');
  $('#my_option').replaceWith('');
});
</script>
```

This is just a quick example that just shows the default dropdown, then when you click an `create` button, it replaces with an input field. There are all kinds of javascript-based solutions.

Another solution is to array this field and in the backend just use `array_filter()` to remove empty:

```
<select name="choose[rowId][]"></select>
<input name="choose[rowId][]"/>
```

If there are 2 values still in the array, then there is a new field being added, if not, then it will take the `select` value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't.

But what you can do is add an `hidden` field which could stock which one to use when the value is returned to the backend. In the backend, your php should check the value of the hidden field and access the right variable.

Hope that will help.